# Sequelize magic method returning null

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Just a bit confused as to why this magic method is returning null. It's probably very simple, but I'm using methods I wouldn't normally (bulkingCreating) and can't currently see it.

Association: `Country.hasOne(Capital, { foreignKey: 'countryId' });`

Populating dummy data:

```
    const countries = await Country.bulkCreate([
        { name: 'England' },
        { name: 'Spain' },
        { name: 'France' },
        { name: 'Canada' }
    ]);

    const capitals = await Capital.bulkCreate([
        { name: 'London' },
        { name: 'Madrid'},
        { name: 'Paris' },
        { name: 'Ottawa' }
    ]);

    countries.forEach((country, index) => {
        country.setCapital(capitals[index]);
    });        

    const country = await Country.findOne({where: {name: 'Spain'}});
    console.log(country.name, Object.keys(country.__proto__)); // Spain / magic methods

    const capital = await country.getCapital();
    console.log(capital); // null
```

The table:

[image: Table]

Am I wrong in thinking `country.getCapital()` should return the relevant entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might guess `setCapital` should be an async function because it makes changes in DB so you need to use `for` instead of `forEach` method that does not support async callbacks:

```js
let index = 0;
for (const country of countries) {
  await country.setCapital(capitals[index]);
  index += 1;
}
```

It would be better to create countries one by one and create capitals for them not relying on the same indexes of both collections (DB might return created records in a different order).

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks. And yeah, normally I wouldn't rely on the indexes, I'm just exploring methods that I've not previously used in a tutorial, but are you saying that `bulkCreate` wouldn't necessarily return the records in the same order as the array that it's passed? Interesting

Comment: but you're right - if the order isn't guaranteed I'm finding it's a pretty inconvenient way of doing it!

Comment: Even if the order of returned records the same as an input array it's not a guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sequelize 5.14+, you can do this in 1 `bulkCreate` using `include` option.

```js
const countries = await Country.bulkCreate([
  { 
    name: 'England',
    Capital: {         // This keyname should be matching with model name.
      name: 'London'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Spain',
    Capital: {
      name: 'Madrid'
    }
  },
  ...
  ], 
  { 
    include: Capital,
    returning: true // If Postgres, add this if you want the created object to be returned.
  }
);
```